# SQL Count not working

Tags: php, mysql, sql

First thing to say is I am somewhat new to the whole SQL prepared statment thing.
Here is my issue, when I try and count the number of times a user has rated a post I am not getting a response, instead I get an odd error. Any help would be appreciated.

```
$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `rate` WHERE `userID`=? AND `postID`=?";
        if($stmt = $connection->prepare($query)){
            $stmt->bind_param("ii", $id, $post_id);
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->bind_result($count);
            $stmt->fetch();
            echo $count;
        } else {
            echo $connection->error;
        }
```

And the error given by the echo $connection->error is:
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

Comment: What is the `>` doing at the end of the quer?

Comment: Thanks, typo when fixing the formatting.

Comment: The error you are getting is not consistent with the code you posted.  What happens when you run the query directly on MariaDB?

Comment: This is where I sound dumb. No idea what MariaDB is, i host though Hostinger, and I view my databsae through PHPmyADMin

Comment: please use `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` on top of your page and let us know if any error is thrown. Add also `echo"id : $id / post_id : $post_id";` before `$query` so when make sure data is properly set

Comment: which api is used to connect with and if successfully? if it isn't `mysqli_` than that's an issue. Also make sure that both variables have value and correspond to the data types for the columns.

Comment: No error is thrown. And i checked the id and post id both are correct, and when i write the query into phpmyadmin it works, just not like this

Comment: also, you can't bind results on `COUNT(*)` if the totals don't match.

Comment: I connect using mysqli, there are other querys and they all work, just this one gets upset

Comment: `COUNT(*) AS totalcount` then bind result on $totalcount EDIT: spoiled by Fred-ii as usual :/ this guy's just too fast ! too furious too ? ^^

Comment: now that ^ you can do.

Comment: That fixed the error, thanks for the help, will keep that in mind in the future :)

Comment: @OldPadawan I'd post that comment of yours as an answer, given it's not just the comment; a better answer will help a lot ;-)

Comment: @OldPadawan *"spoiled by Fred-ii as usual :/ this guy just too fast ! too furious too ?"* -  well, I only offered an additional helping hand ;-) this one's all yours if you want it.

Comment: I'll take it, thanks, with credit to you though :) glad it helped

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated by @Fred-ii ->

```
    `COUNT(*) AS totalcount` then bind result on $totalcount
```

it's also important to have `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` on top of pages in pre-prod